# man does not work (too many arguments)

Tags: man

I get this an error when trying to run `man` on a Linux system:

```
$ LC_ALL=C man man

man: Too many arguments
Try 'man --help' or 'man --usage' for more information.
```

My `man` command doesn't seem to be an alias:

```
command -v man: /usr/bin/man
```

What's going on?

Comment: What is the output of "alias man" or simply "alias"?

Comment: Is your `man` an alias? Check with `type man` or `command -v man`.

Comment: alias ll='ls -l --color=auto |grep '\'' -'\'''
alias ls='ls --color=auto'

Comment: command -v man:    /usr/bin/man

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are seeing on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: _$ LC_ALL=C man man_ : What is that ? LC_ALL ?

Comment: Did you try "dpkg-reconfigure man-db"?

Comment: @jayooin It's setting the default locale to the standard `C` locale.  There is nothing strange about that bit.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Thanks for the enlightning. 
@NeedHelp, Have you tried running with absolute path ? `/usr/bin/man` ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check the existence of `MANOPT` variable.

> `MANOPT`
>   If `$MANOPT` is set, it will be parsed prior to `man`'s command line and is expected to be in a similar format.

<sup>[source](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/man/)</sup>

Example:

```
$ MANOPT='foo bar'
$ export MANOPT
$ man man
man: Too many arguments
Try 'man --help' or 'man --usage' for more information.
$
```

An obvious ad-hoc fix is to `unset MANOPT`. Then you should investigate where the variable came from.

Comment: So why is the error `Too many arguments`? Like if I `export MANOPT=foo`, why doesn't it say `No manual entry for foo`?

Comment: @wjandrea `man` is probably splitting `MANOPT` on spaces and then running the resulting array through `getopt(3)`, and complain if any non-option arguments (ie arguments not starting with a dash) are left. They could've used a better error message. Anyways, even a **single** argument is too much for it: try `MANOPT=man man man`.